# .htaccess - move site from .html to .php, but exclude a folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I've got a new site, and put the old version of the site in an /old folder.

The new site has the same page names as the old one, except they all now have a .php extension.

I've got the following rule for SEO to direct all the .html files to .php

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.mysite.com$1.php
```

But I still need to be able to access everything in the /old folder - the redirect is obviously redirecting the files in here too (e.g. mysite.com/old/mypage.html is going to mysite.com/old/mypage.php - I need the .html version)

I've tried to find out for myself, but I'm not sure about all the RedirectXYZ commands.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?!/old)(.*)\.html$ http://www.mysite.com$1.php
```

`(?!/old)` rejects a match containing the string `/old` at this position. We use `^` to restrict this to the beginning of the string being matched against.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It didn't work at first, so I added $1 into the url just to see what it was storing, and noticed that the actual page name is in $1. So replaced $2 with $1

Comment: @Josh Okay, that means mod_rewrite isn't assigning a group to `(?!/old)`. Fixing my answer.